# Retriving data from database based on user input

Tags: php, ms-access

I am new to php, and I am learning the basics, I designed a form that has a dynamic drop down menu where the options are populated directly from my Access DB. After the user choose an option, the information related to that option would be displayed in a operate page, but that does not work properly. I run over my code for days and I do not seem to get what is wrong. The commented code seems to be my source of problem.
this is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// This would be the value passed from the previous php page
$option =$_POST['myDropdown'];

// for testing purposes
print("$option");

// print image of the menu item or dish
print <<< HERE

<p>
<img src = "DishesPictures/Dish-$option.png" border="1" bordercolor="black"
       alt = "die: $option" />

</p>
HERE;

$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO"); 


 $connString= "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
Data Source=e:\\ectserver\\naljalidi\\Database\\Menu.mdb";
    //creates the connection object and define the connection string

// for testing purposes
print("$connString");

$rs=$conn->Execute("SELECT ItemID,ItemDesc,Price FROM Menu WHERE ItemID=$option;");
//if (!$rs->EOF)
//{
  // $ItemID=$rs->Fields("ItemID");
  // $ItemDesc=$rs->Fields("ItemDesc");
  // print("$ItemID");
  // print("$ItemDesc");
//}


$rs->Close();


?>
</body>

</html>
```

My DB information:
Database Name: Menu
Table: only one , named Menu
Field: ItemID(PK, AutoNumber), ItemDesc(Text), Price(Currancy)

Any help? Thank you

Comment: You're using html inside php tags as it is. You should either echo html or close php tag before using html tags

Comment: I am using print insted of echo, and I would like to know what html tags you are referring too,if it is the img one then I removed it and tested my code but still it is the same problem. Thanx anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the code:

```
$conn->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC);  
$rs=$conn->Execute("SELECT ItemID,ItemDesc,Price FROM Menu WHERE ItemID=$option;");
if (!$rs) {  
print $conn->ErrorMsg();  
 } else
{
 $ItemID=$rs->Fields['ItemID'];
 $ItemDesc=$rs->Fields['ItemDesc'];
 print("$ItemID");
 print("$ItemDesc");
}
```