# Cannot connect to MS Access DB with PHP : SQLSTATE[IM002]

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I am trying to get data from a MS Access DB (.mdb) but I'm getting:

> échec de connexion: SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0
>   [Microsoft][Gestionnaire de pilotes ODBC] Source de données
>   introuvable et nom de pilote non spécifié.

English:

> connection failure: SQLSTATE [IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft]
>   [ODBC driver manager] data source not found and driver name
>   unspecified.

I have : Office 365 Business 32-bit
 installed. Already installed the latest Access Database Engine 32-bit. Uncommented " extension=pdo_odbc " in php.ini.
 Added the "Microsoft Access Driver" to the list of drivers.

```
$dbName = 'C:\wamp64\www\Test\Workgroup.mdb';
if (!file_exists($dbName))
{
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
else
{
    try{
        //$dbName = 'Workgroup.mdb';
        $cnx = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; Dbq=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
        echo "connected successfully";
        return $cnx;
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        die ("failed to connect: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: $dbName in the Try block does not appear to have full file path. Why do you set the variable here?

Comment: Just forgot to comment it, it was for the purpose of testing.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103712/php-connecting-to-access-database-mdb